# ClassNotFoundException com.twilio.voice.CallInvite when reading ConnectionService Bundle extras in onCreateIncomingConnection

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm upgrading a Flutter library to use a Twilio Voice integrated with a [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) for native call management. To accomplish this, one has to extend a `ConnectionService` (inherits from a `Service` with associated communication methods, i.e. `Intent`s)

---

#### Background & Context

To receive incoming call (via a notification manager like FCM), one needs to notify the `ConnectionService` of an incoming call using

```kotlin
override fun onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?, request: ConnectionRequest?): Connection {
    super.onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection")'
    // ... code goes here
    // return new Connection(...)
}
```

With this `onCreateIncomingConnection`, it will ask the native 'Phone Call' app to show an incoming call with parameters you provide, e.g. showing the incoming caller number with [Connection.setAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection#setAddress(android.net.Uri,%20int))

This additional information can be passed into the `ConnectionService` by adding them to an extras `Bundle` with the Key [TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS) (for incoming calls) which is then added to a new `Bundle` e.g.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66893429/4628115)

```java
private fun handleFCMCallInvite(callInvite: CallInvite, notificationId: Int) {
    // Get telecom manager
    val telecomManager = getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager

    // Get PhoneAccountHandle
    val caller = callInvite.from!!.toString()
    val componentName = ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, TwilioVoiceConnectionService::class.java.name)
    val phoneAccountHandle = PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, caller)

    // Create my Bundle containing information e.g. notificationId and callInvite
    val myBundle = Bundle()
    myBundle.putInt(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)
    myBundle.putParcelable(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INVITE, callInvite)

    // Add new incoming call to the telecom manager
    telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, Bundle().apply {
        putBundle(EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS, myBundle)
        putParcelable(EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle)
    })
}
```

---

#### Problem

The issue comes in when trying to `unparcel()` the `CallInvite` from Bundled extras in the `ConnectionService`'s [onCreateIncomingConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService#onCreateIncomingConnection(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20android.telecom.ConnectionRequest)) implementation, see as follows:

```java
override fun onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?, request: ConnectionRequest?): Connection {
    super.onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection")
    val connection: Connection = VoipConnection(applicationContext)
    connection.extras = request?.extras

    var ci: CallInvite? = null
    val myBundle: Bundle? = connection.extras.getBundle(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS);
    if(myBundle != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection: myBundle is not null")

        /// --------------------------------------------------------
        /// This next line throws the ClassNotFoundException occurs
        /// --------------------------------------------------------
        if (myBundle.containsKey(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INVITE) ) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection: myBundle contains INCOMING_CALL_INVITE")
            ci = myBundle.getParcelable(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INVITE)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection: myBundle does not contain INCOMING_CALL_INVITE")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection: myBundle is null")
    }

    ...
}
```

As shown in the snippet above, when calling `myBundle.containsKey()` with a valid key any time I have a [CallInvite](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-voice-android/docs/latest/com/twilio/voice/CallInvite.html) object bundled in. If I only pass in e.g. `notificationId`, contains and accessors work as intended.

When including the `CallInvite` in the bundle, I get the following exception:

*Note: `CallInvite` implements `Parcelable`

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.twilio.voice.CallInvite
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.voice.CallInvite
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3403)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3337)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3239)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3636)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:516)
    at com.twilio.twilio_voice.connectionservice.TwilioVoiceConnectionService.onCreateIncomingConnection(TwilioVoiceConnectionService.kt:43)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.createConnection(ConnectionService.java:2061)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.access$400(ConnectionService.java:96)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService$2$1.loggedRun(ConnectionService.java:914)
    at android.telecom.Logging.Runnable$1.run(Runnable.java:37)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.onAccountsInitialized(ConnectionService.java:3272)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.access$5000(ConnectionService.java:96)
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService$5$1.loggedRun(ConnectionService.java:2577)
    at android.telecom.Logging.Runnable$1.run(Runnable.java:37)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.voice.CallInvite
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1358)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3403) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3337) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3239) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3636) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:516) 
    at com.twilio.twilio_voice.connectionservice.TwilioVoiceConnectionService.onCreateIncomingConnection(TwilioVoiceConnectionService.kt:43) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.createConnection(ConnectionService.java:2061) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.access$400(ConnectionService.java:96) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService$2$1.loggedRun(ConnectionService.java:914) 
    at android.telecom.Logging.Runnable$1.run(Runnable.java:37) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.onAccountsInitialized(ConnectionService.java:3272) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService.access$5000(ConnectionService.java:96) 
    at android.telecom.ConnectionService$5$1.loggedRun(ConnectionService.java:2577) 
    at android.telecom.Logging.Runnable$1.run(Runnable.java:37) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

---

#### Libraries, etc

`build.gradle` (module)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
android {
    compileSdk 33
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.twilio:voice-android:6.2.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.2.1")
    ...
}
```

---

### UPDATE 1

Using the last working solution (Java), I resolved to parcelling and unparcelling immediately to emulate what's happening in the background, seems there might be a problem here.

```java
public class VoiceFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ... valid message
        handleInvite(callInvite, notificationId);
        //...
    }

    private void handleInvite(CallInvite callInvite, int notificationId) {
        Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
        p.writeParcelable(callInvite, 0);
        ClassLoader classLoader = getApplicationContext().getClassLoader();
        CallInvite ci = p.readParcelable(classLoader); // <----------------- ci is always null
        if(ci != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "handleInvite: " + ci.getCallSid());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleInvite: null");
        }
    }

}
```

The same occurs on with Kotlin, though I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `CallInvite`.

So far, I've traced the issue to [Parcel.readParcelableCreator(@Nullable ClassLoader)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/400aaf9/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#2868) (for Android 11, API 30)

```java
public final Parcelable.Creator<?> readParcelableCreator(@Nullable ClassLoader loader) {
        String name = readString();
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Parcelable.Creator<?> creator;
```

`name` is always null, thus returns null when calling `Parcel.readParcelable`.

*This occurs on both Android 11 & 12 (API 30, 31)*

Answer (score 1):

An issue I explored in detail on [Twilio Android Quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/issues/561) documented a Parcel issue, and provided some insight into the cause of the problem.

The cause being the current thread's `ClassLoader` isn't the same that initialized (loaded) the Voice SDK's class loader as suggested by `@afalls-twilio` in his comment [here](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/issues/561#issuecomment-1675435831)

This was confirmed and discussed in some detail by [David Wasser at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589962/4628115).

##### TL;DR Solution

A simple line addition when reading the bundle adds the class to be found i.e.

```kotlin
val myBundle: Bundle? = connection.extras.getBundle(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS);
myBundle.classLoader = CallInvite::class.java.classLoader
// read CallInvite from Bundle as required
```